# trying to have a row of icons on bottom of screen that navigates to different activities

Tags: android

Iv seen some apps that navigate by having a row of icons at the buttom of the screen.  At first I thought this would be a typer of menu, but I googled it and could not find a menu type that was a row of icons on buttom of screen.

Does any body know how these apps do this????

Comment: try googling `bottom navigation view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is good tutorial to get you started on `Bottom Navigation View`

[Codepath Tutorial - Bottom Navigation View](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Bottom-Navigation-Views)